# Domestic or international check in at Beijing? Flying PEK-XMN-MNL on one ticket

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, china, domestic-travel

This is my first time not on a direct flight to my final destination.

I'm flying from Beijing to Manila with a stop in Xiamen. When I check in at Beijing, does the first flight count as a domestic or international flight?

Comment: It counts as domestic, and then you'll clear passport control at Xiamen.

Answer (score 4):

I flew out of Beijing in November. The departure boards and my boarding pass both told me a gate with a letter and a number. I believe mine was E7. The signs then said both International/Domestic (more complicated than that because Macao, Hong Kong, and Taiwan are not international in China's opinion, so it's "International plus Macao, Hong Kong, and Taiwan" / "Domestic") as well as indicating the letters, eg "E Gates."

As a result you're unlikely to get it wrong. That said, it seems likely that your first leg will be domestic, and you'll do an international departure (including passport checks) in Xiamen.

Comment: Correct, OP will clear passport control in Xiamen